# Oracle SQL - Update Set field to value Case When another field equals something

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to have this update happen only on the condition that another field is equal to a certain value? ie. I only want to set `inv.schedule_finish` to a different value if `inv.nl_sch_chg = 1`.

Is it something along the lines of `SET inv.schedule_finish = CASE WHEN inv.nl_sch_change = 1 THEN ... END CASE;` or is there a better way to achieve this?

This is my statement currently:

```
UPDATE INV_INVESTMENTS inv
SET inv.schedule_finish = (SELECT TRUNC(odf.nl_rev_enddate) + 1/(24*60*60)
                           FROM ODF_CA_CHANGE odf
                           JOIN RIM_RISKS_AND_ISSUES rim ON rim.ID = odf.ID
                           WHERE rim.ID = ${gel_objectInstanceId})
WHERE inv.ID = (SELECT rim.PK_ID
                FROM RIM_RISKS_AND_ISSUES rim
                JOIN INV_INVESTMENTS inv ON inv.ID = rim.PK_ID
                JOIN ODF_CA_CHANGE odf ON odf.ID = rim.ID
                WHERE odf.ID = ${gel_objectInstanceId});
```

Thanks kindly

Comment: Why not simply adding `inv.nl_sch_chg = 1`to the where clause: `WHERE inv.ID = ... AND inv.nl_sch_chg = 1`?

Comment: @Radagast81 Is that just as/more efficient as a case statement?

Comment: It depends but it's general more efficient as you don't update all data rows but only the data rows with `inv.nl_sch_chg = 1`. So it's as least as efficient as the case statement...

Comment: Okay, perfect. Thanks. Want to add that as an answer and I'll accept it (since you answered my question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the condition to your where clause:

```
UPDATE INV_INVESTMENTS inv
SET inv.schedule_finish = (SELECT TRUNC(odf.nl_rev_enddate) + 1/(24*60*60)
                           FROM ODF_CA_CHANGE odf
                           JOIN RIM_RISKS_AND_ISSUES rim ON rim.ID = odf.ID
                           WHERE rim.ID = ${gel_objectInstanceId})
WHERE inv.ID = (SELECT rim.PK_ID
                FROM RIM_RISKS_AND_ISSUES rim
                JOIN INV_INVESTMENTS inv ON inv.ID = rim.PK_ID
                JOIN ODF_CA_CHANGE odf ON odf.ID = rim.ID
                WHERE odf.ID = ${gel_objectInstanceId})
AND inv.nl_sch_change = 1
```

This way only the rows with `inv.nl_sch_change = 1` will get updated as otherwise all rows will be updated regardless if the data changes or not. So this should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my observations on your query:

1. "=" used in SET and WHERE clause of UPDATE statement suggests that the sub-queries used in these two places return one and only one value.
2. SELECT queries in SET and WHERE clauses are almost similar except for one additional join on INV_INVESTMENTS (same table which are updating).

Now, coming to a better way of handling this. You can handle this in two ways:

1. Join all tables using a single query (SELECT ROWID from INV_INVESTMENTS) and make it an explicit cursor. Use BULK COLLECT INTO and FORALL UPDATE statements to update the INV_INVESTMENTS table using ROWID. You have to enable SAVE_EXCEPTION clause and handle exceptions accordingly.
2. Use your UPDATE statement excluding "JOIN INV_INVESTMENTS inv ON inv.ID = rim.PK_ID". We can access "inv" from "UPDATE INV_INVESTMENTS inv" and add "inv.ID = rim.PK_ID" in existing WHERE clause of 2nd sub-query.